# Install ruby gem (compass) with chef solo

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, compass, chef-solo, berkshelf

Is there an easy way to install ruby gems with chef-solo that don't have their own cookbook?

In particular, I would like to install [compass](/questions/tagged/compass). There does not seem to be a cookbook for it and I would like to avoid writing my own, if possible.

As an example, to install npm packages, I can add this to my `solo.json` configuration:

```
"nodejs": {
    "npm_packages": [
        {
          "name": "grunt-cli"
        },
        {
          "name": "bower"
        }
    ]
},
```

(using the nodejs cookbook https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nodejs)

Can I do something similar for ruby gems?

Comment: The correct answer here is going to be that you need to write your own cookbook.  Trying to use Chef without writing cookbooks is like fighting with both hands tied behind your back and both legs chopped off.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`gem_package` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_gem_package.html) for that:

```ruby
gem_package 'compass' do
  gem_binary '/usr/bin/gem'
  action :install
end
```

If you want to intstall the package using only node attributes, maybe [the `rvm` cookbook](https://github.com/martinisoft/chef-rvm/tree/v0.9.4#-global_gems) can help you with that, depending on your use case. For example:

```ruby
node['rvm']['global_gems'] = [
  { 'name'    => 'compass' }
]
```

Comment: Obligatory "using rvm on servers not recommended" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Chef offers both the `gem_package`, as well as the `chef_gem` resources. In @sethvargo 's words from [here](https://sethvargo.com/using-gems-with-chef/):

> The chef_gem and gem_package resources are both used to install Ruby
>   gems. For any machine on which the chef-client is installed, there are
>   two instances of Ruby. One is the standard, system-wide instance of
>   Ruby and the other is a dedicated instance that is available only to
>   the chef-client. Use the chef_gem resource to install gems into the
>   instance of Ruby that is dedicated to the chef-client. Use the
>   gem_package resource to install all other gems (i.e. install gems
>   system-wide).